# Are they called "environment" or "environmental" variables?

Tags: environment-variables, terminology

I've always used the term "environment variable", but I have a well-informed colleague who consistently says "environment**al** variable".

Which one is correct?

Comment: I guess it would depend on what context. "Environmental variables" sounds more like something I'd hear in my lab classes. If you're dealing with sensor data for example, environmental variable may make perfect sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Environment Variable

While *environmental variable* is used occasionally, **environment variable** is overwhelmingly more common:

- Wikipedia: [Environment Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)
- Arch Linux wiki: [Environment variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables)

  - "environment var" => 28 instances
  - "environmental var" => 3 instances
- [POSIX.1‐2017, Chapter 8. Environment Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)
   (title)
- Linux man pages:

  - [`environ(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) -- "Environment variables may be..."
  - [`getenv(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) -- "get an environment variable"
  - [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) -- just "environment"
  - [`bash(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ENVIRONMENT) -- mostly just "environment", but occasionally "environment variable" and never "environmental"
- Linux kernel

  - `git grep -i 'environment var' | wc -l` => 183
  - `git grep -i 'environmental var' | wc -l` => 2
- MSDN

  - [`getenv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=msvc-170) -- "Environment variable name"
  - [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable)
  - [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0)
- Python

  - [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)
- Perl

  - [`Env`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Env) -- "Perl maintains environment variables..."
- Google

  - [image: Searching for "get environmental variable" shows results for "get environment variable"]
- Stack Overflow

  - An [`environment-variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environment-variables) tag exists, but [`environmental-variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environmental-variables) does not
  - There are 90,719 results for ["environment variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22environment+variable%22) but only 4,345 results for ["environmental variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22environmental+variable%22)

Answer (score 2):

"**Environment Variables**" is the correct.

And as you have mentioned about MSDN, I would like to further add that on Windows Machine, the start search also shows "**Edit the system environment variables**" as follows:

[image]